# Azure LogicApp ARM template and AzSK checker

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps, azure-rm-template

I am working on ARM template development for LogicApp and want to make my ARM template complaint to AzSk.

In my template I have following required objects for this component:

```
        "ipAddressRangeForContents": {
            "type": "array",
            "defaultValue": [],
            "metadata": {
              "description": "(AzSk required this parameter to be set) IPv4 or IPv6 address range, this will restrict content IP range. This array should have object as a member with following key 'addressRange'. You can specify as many subnets as you want"
            }
        },
        "ipAddressRangeForInbound": {
          "type": "array",
          "defaultValue": [],
          "metadata": {
            "description": "(AzSk required this parameter to be set) IPv4 or IPv6 address range, this will restrict inbound IP range. This array should have object as a member with following key 'addressRange'. You can specify as many subnets as you want. Default value is empty array which will restric access to 'Only other Logic Apps'."
          }
```

Here is an example from parameters file for same section:

```
        "ipAddressRangeForContents": {
            "value": [
                {
                    "addressRange": "10.123.0.0/24"
                },
                {
                    "addressRange": "10.124.0.0/24"
                }
            ]
        },
        "ipAddressRangeForInbound": {
            "value": [
                {
                    "addressRange": "10.135.0.0/24"
                },
                {    
                    "addressRange": "10.136.0.0/24"
                }
            ]
        }
```

The reason I implemented it this way is flexibility for user to specify as many address ranges as user wants.

AzSk returning me an error if I scan my ARM template:

```
Starting analysis: [FileName: .\logicapp.json]
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Failed: [Azure_LogicApps_AuthZ_Provide_Triggers_Access_Control]
Failed: [Azure_LogicApps_AuthZ_Provide_Contents_Access_Control]
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Summary  Total Failed
-------  ----- ------
High         2      2
------  ------ ------
Total        2      2
------  ------ ------
```

Even if my template has these parameters.

The reason it's failing it cannot locate property addressRange inside ARM template:

```
ExpectedProperty
$.properties.accessControl.triggers.allowedCallerIpAddresses.addressRange
$.properties.accessControl.contents.allowedCallerIpAddresses.addressRange
```

I can fix it by hardcoding my template to:

```
"properties": {
                "accessControl": {
                  "contents": {
                    "allowedCallerIpAddresses": {
                        "addressRange": "[variables('some_range')]"
                    }
```

But this will make it less functional since it can accept only one addressRange at deployment phase.

Is there is a way to make template complaint and flexible in the same time?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I thought I couldn't use copy on parameters, but I was wrong, trying to implement that. Here is the link for reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-create-multiple trying to implement

Comment: copy function didn't work, getting same errors. So question is actual